# DataContext seems to be pulling 2 copies of the same record from the database

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, datacontext

I have a DataContext that seems two be pulling two copies of the same record out of the database.  There's only one record of this kind in the database.

Here the code that is doing it:

```
dataAccessContext =
                    new DataAccessDataContext("Data Source=" + SettingsManager.OpsMgrSettings.DBDIR +
                                              ";default lock timeout=10000");
```

When I go through the debug of the dataAccessContext after calling the above, I look at an entity called JobNumbers.  Inside of that entity, there is another entity called SafetyIssues, which has 2 records instead of 1.  They are the exact same record.  The database only shows one record, but some how it's pulling the same record twice in the dataAccessContext.

Even when I bind to a listbox later on it shows the same record in the listbox twice.  If I click one, they BOTH get selected.

Here is the dbml design for the JobNumbers entity (if this helps):

```
  <Table Name="JobNumber" Member="JobNumbers">
    <Type Name="JobNumber">
      <Column Name="JobID" AutoSync="OnInsert" Type="System.Int32" DbType="Int NOT NULL" IsPrimaryKey="true" CanBeNull="false" />
      <Column Name="Jobno" Type="System.String" DbType="nVarChar(50)" CanBeNull="true" />
      <Column Name="LocnID" Type="System.String" DbType="nChar(2)" CanBeNull="true" />
      <Column Name="Date" Type="System.DateTime" DbType="DateTime" CanBeNull="true" />
      <Column Name="version" Type="System.Int32" DbType="Int NOT NULL" CanBeNull="false" />
      <Column Name="NumJobNo" Type="System.Int32" DbType="Int" CanBeNull="true" />
      <Column Name="SQ3Username" Type="System.String" DbType="nVarChar(50)" CanBeNull="true" />
      <Column Name="SQ3Done" Type="System.Boolean" DbType="Bit" CanBeNull="true" />
      <Column Name="OrigJobNo" Type="System.String" DbType="NVarChar(20)" CanBeNull="true" />
      <Column Name="Updated" Type="System.Byte" DbType="Bit" CanBeNull="true" />
      <Column Name="Modified" Type="System.Int16" DbType="tinyint" CanBeNull="false" />
      <Column Name="JobTargetSafetySubmissions" Type="System.Int32" DbType="int" CanBeNull="false" />
      <Column Name="SQ3Completed" Type="System.Int16" DbType="smallint" CanBeNull="false" />
      <Column Name="Conflict" Type="System.Boolean" DbType="bit" CanBeNull="false" />
      <Association Name="JobNumber_EAC_Personnel" Member="EAC_Personnels" ThisKey="JobID" OtherKey="JobID" Type="EAC_Personnel" />
      <Association Name="JobNumber_La_Personnel" Member="LA_Personnel" ThisKey="JobID" OtherKey="JobID" Type="La_Personnel" />
      <Association Name="JobNumber_GWD_Header2" Member="GWD_Header2s" ThisKey="JobID" OtherKey="jobid" Type="GWD_Header2" Cardinality="One" />
      <Association Name="JobNumber_MonitorInfo" Member="MonitorInfos" ThisKey="JobID" OtherKey="JobID" Type="MonitorInfo" Cardinality="One" />
      <Association Name="JobNumber_NA_Salesman" Member="NA_Salesmans" ThisKey="JobID" OtherKey="JobID" Type="NA_Salesman" Cardinality="One" />
      <Association Name="JobNumber_NA_WRdetail" Member="NA_WRdetails" ThisKey="JobID" OtherKey="JobID" Type="NA_WRdetail" Cardinality="One" />
      <Association Name="JobNumber_NA_BillingCompany" Member="NA_BillingCompanies" ThisKey="JobID" OtherKey="JobID" Type="NA_BillingCompany" Cardinality="One" />
      <Association Name="JobNumber_NA_Header" Member="NA_Headers" ThisKey="JobID" OtherKey="JobID" Type="NA_Header" Cardinality="One" />
      <Association Name="JobNumber_Subcontractor" Member="Subcontractors" ThisKey="JobID" OtherKey="JobID" Type="Subcontractor" Cardinality="One" />
      <Association Name="JobNumber_NA_Holedetail" Member="NA_Holedetails" ThisKey="JobID" OtherKey="JobID" Type="NA_Holedetail" Cardinality="One" />
      <Association Name="JobNumber_NA_WL_Company" Member="NA_WL_Companies" ThisKey="JobID" OtherKey="JobID" Type="NA_WL_Company" Cardinality="One" />
      <Association Name="JobNumber_Rpt_Detail" Member="Rpt_Details" ThisKey="JobID" OtherKey="JobID" Type="Rpt_Detail" Cardinality="One" />
      <Association Name="JobNumber_NA_RigDetail" Member="NA_RigDetails" ThisKey="JobID" OtherKey="JobID" Type="NA_RigDetail" Cardinality="One" />
      <Association Name="JobNumber_EAC_Header" Member="EAC_Headers" ThisKey="JobID" OtherKey="JobID" Type="EAC_Header" Cardinality="One" />
      <Association Name="JobNumber_SafetyIssue" Member="SafetyIssues" ThisKey="JobID" OtherKey="JobID" Type="SafetyIssue" />
      <Association Name="JobNumber_SafetyIssueTotals" Member="SafetyIssueTotals" ThisKey="JobID" OtherKey="JobID" Type="SafetyIssueTotals" Cardinality="One" />
      <Association Name="JobNumber_JobService" Member="JobServices" ThisKey="JobID" OtherKey="JobID" Type="JobService" />
      <Association Name="JobNumber_NA_InvoiceHeader" Member="NA_InvoiceHeaders" ThisKey="JobID" OtherKey="JobID" Type="NA_InvoiceHeader" />
      <Association Name="JobNumber_JobSQ" Member="JobSQs" ThisKey="JobID" OtherKey="JobID" Type="JobSQ" />
      <Association Name="JobNumber_LA_Header" Member="LA_Headers" ThisKey="JobID" OtherKey="JobID" Type="LA_Header" Cardinality="One" />
      <Association Name="JobNumber_LA_Invoice" Member="LA_Invoices" ThisKey="JobID" OtherKey="JobID" Type="LA_Invoice" />
      <Association Name="JobNumber_FE_extra" Member="FE_extras" ThisKey="JobID" OtherKey="JobID" Type="FE_extra" Cardinality="One" />
      <Association Name="JobNumber_FE_Header" Member="FE_Headers" ThisKey="JobID" OtherKey="JobID" Type="FE_Header" />
      <Association Name="JobNumber_FailEquipList" Member="FailEquipLists" ThisKey="JobID" OtherKey="JobID" Type="FailEquipList" />
      <Association Name="JobNumber_JobPricing" Member="JobPricings" ThisKey="JobID" OtherKey="JobID" Type="JobPricing" />
      <Association Name="JobNumber_Equip" Member="Equips" ThisKey="JobID" OtherKey="JobID" Type="Equip" />
      <Association Name="JobNumber_SafetyIssuesTotals" Member="SafetyIssuesTotals" ThisKey="JobID" OtherKey="JobID" Type="SafetyIssuesTotals" Cardinality="One" />
      <Association Name="JobNumber_EAC_Invoice" Member="EAC_Invoices" ThisKey="JobID" OtherKey="JobID" Type="EAC_Invoice" />
      <Association Name="JobNumber_RunningMode" Member="RunningModes" ThisKey="JobID" OtherKey="JobID" Type="RunningMode" Cardinality="One" />
      <Association Name="JobNumber_CorrectionsApplied" Member="CorrectionsApplieds" ThisKey="JobID" OtherKey="JobID" Type="CorrectionsApplied" Cardinality="One" />
      <Association Name="JobNumber_JobInvoice" Member="JobInvoices" ThisKey="JobID" OtherKey="JobID" Type="JobInvoice" />
      <Association Name="JobNumber_GWDRunSummaryData" Member="GWDRunSummaryDatas" ThisKey="JobID" OtherKey="jobid" Type="GWDRunSummaryData" Cardinality="One" />
      <Association Name="JobNumber_InvoiceReportingTable" Member="InvoiceReportingTables" ThisKey="JobID" OtherKey="JobID" Type="InvoiceReportingTable" />
      <Association Name="Location_JobNumber" Member="Location" ThisKey="LocnID" OtherKey="LocnID" Type="Location" IsForeignKey="true" />
    </Type>
    </Table>
```

Here the dbml for the SateyIssues entity (if this helps):

```
  <Table Name="SafetyIssues">
    <Type Name="SafetyIssue">
      <Column Name="JobID" Type="System.Int32" DbType="Int" CanBeNull="true" />
      <Column Name="JobSafetyNo" Type="System.String" DbType="nVarChar(50) NOT NULL" CanBeNull="false" />
      <Column Name="SafetyCategory" Type="System.Int32" DbType="Int NOT NULL" CanBeNull="false" />
      <Column Name="IssueDate" Type="System.DateTime" DbType="DateTime NOT NULL" CanBeNull="false" />
      <Column Name="CorrectiveActionRefNo" Type="System.String" DbType="nVarChar(50) NOT NULL" CanBeNull="false" />
      <Column Name="SafetyInitiative" Type="System.String" DbType="nVarChar(50) NOT NULL" CanBeNull="false" />
      <Column Name="Topic_Summary" Type="System.String" DbType="nVarChar(4000) NOT NULL" CanBeNull="false" />
      <Column Name="Feedback_FollowUp" Type="System.String" DbType="nVarChar(4000) NOT NULL" CanBeNull="false" />
      <Column Name="LinkID" Type="System.Int32" DbType="Int NOT NULL IDENTITY" IsPrimaryKey="true" IsDbGenerated="true" CanBeNull="false" />
      <Association Name="SafetyIssue_SafetyIssueEngineer" Member="SafetyIssueEngineers" ThisKey="LinkID" OtherKey="LinkID" Type="SafetyIssueEngineer" />
      <Association Name="JobNumber_SafetyIssue" Member="JobNumber" ThisKey="JobID" OtherKey="JobID" Type="JobNumber" IsForeignKey="true" />
      <Association Name="SafetyCategory_SafetyIssue" Member="SafetyCategory1" ThisKey="SafetyCategory" OtherKey="SafetyCategoryID" Type="SafetyCategory" IsForeignKey="true" />
    </Type>
  </Table>
```

dbml partial class code that I wrote:

```
    partial class SafetyIssue
    {

        partial void OnLoaded()
        {
            JobNumber.CalculateSafetyIssueTotals();  
        }

    }

    partial class SafetyIssueTotals
    {
       public void RefreshTotals(List<SafetyIssue> safetyIssues)
       {
           TotalSubmissions = safetyIssues.Count(c => c.SafetyCategory == 1);
           TotalInductions = safetyIssues.Count(c => c.SafetyCategory == 2);
           TotalSafetyMeetings = safetyIssues.Count(c => c.SafetyCategory == 3); 
           TotalToolboxTalk = safetyIssues.Count(c => c.SafetyCategory == 4);
           TotalRecognitions = safetyIssues.Count(c => c.SafetyCategory == 5);
           TotalIncidents = safetyIssues.Count(c => c.SafetyCategory == 6);
           ActualSafetySubmissions = safetyIssues.Count(c => c.JobSafetyNo.Trim() != "");
       }

    }


    partial class JobNumber:IDataErrorInfo
    {

        public void CalculateSafetyIssueTotals()
        {
            if (SafetyIssuesTotals == null)
                SafetyIssuesTotals = new SafetyIssuesTotals();

/* If I comment the part below out, it works.  Seems like if I use the SafetyIssues entity at all (in this case SafetyIssues.Count() to  assign things, the problem happens */

            SafetyIssuesTotals.TotalActualSafetySubmissions = SafetyIssues.Count;
            SafetyIssuesTotals.TotalIncidents =
                SafetyIssues.Count(s => s.SafetyCategory1 != null && s.SafetyCategory1.SafetyCategoryID == 6);
            SafetyIssuesTotals.TotalInductions =
                SafetyIssues.Count(s => s.SafetyCategory1 != null && s.SafetyCategory1.SafetyCategoryID == 2);
            SafetyIssuesTotals.TotalRecognitions =
                SafetyIssues.Count(s => s.SafetyCategory1 != null && s.SafetyCategory1.SafetyCategoryID == 5);
            SafetyIssuesTotals.TotalSafetyMeetings =
                SafetyIssues.Count(s => s.SafetyCategory1 != null && s.SafetyCategory1.SafetyCategoryID == 3);
            SafetyIssuesTotals.TotalSubmissions =
                SafetyIssues.Count(s => s.SafetyCategory1 != null && s.SafetyCategory1.SafetyCategoryID == 1);
            SafetyIssuesTotals.TotalToolboxTalk =
                SafetyIssues.Count(s => s.SafetyCategory1 != null && s.SafetyCategory1.SafetyCategoryID == 4);

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        }

        public bool NoReportedSafetyIssues
        {
            get
            {
                _noReportedSafetyIssues = SafetyIssues.Count == 0;
                return _noReportedSafetyIssues;
            }
            set
            {
                _noReportedSafetyIssues = value;
                SendPropertyChanged("NoReportedSafetyIssues");
            }
        }

    }
```

I just can't see why it is pulling 2 copies of the same record.  Hope you guys can help.

Comment: Might be unrelated, but `SafetyIssueTotals` seems to be declared twice in the JobNumber entity associations.

Comment: By the way, not sure if this is just there for the sake of having a code example, but checking if the response is null, and if it isn't setting it to a variable is going to run the query twice. You would be better off doing something like `var jobNum = query.SingleOrDefault(); if(jobNum == null) { // use jobNum here. }`. That way you'll reduce db calls.

Comment: After doing some more debugging, I have found out that the first part of the code I posted is not involved.  This is happening as soon as I create the DataContext.  I'll edit my question to show where I first notice it.  And good point about the null thing.  The SafetyIssueTotals is unrelated to this.

Comment: edited, for the new discovery that I made.  Still puzzling me

Comment: The two SafetyIssueTotals you see are actually two different tables (one of which doesn't need to be there anymore).  They are actually spelled different SafetyIssueTotals and SafetyIssuesTotals, but they are irrelevant to this issue.

Comment: Can you show some code from the `DataAccessDataContext`?

Comment: it's a lot of code in there.  I'll try to post the relevant parts of it. Don't know if it will be incomplete though.

Comment: @Kazuo  It's kind of hard for me to pick and choose what code is relevant in the auto generated DataAccessDataContext

Comment: Okay guys. More truth unfolds.  I forgot to check the code that I put in my dbml partial classes.  I posted an edit.  I also found out, after looking at the dbml code, that if I comment out the code for SafetyIssues.OnLoaded(), that everything works fine. Now I am just trying to find out which part of that function call is causing the problem.  It doesn't seem to happen until after all of that is called though. And by the way, @Ocelot you may be right about the SafetyIssueTotals in it's relevance, indirectly

Comment: More discovery.  In my dbml partial class for JobNumber, there is a function called CalculateSafetyIssueTotals().  It seems like if I use the SafetyIssues to assign a value to something, the problem happens.  If I don't do this, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I fixed the issue.  The problem was in my dbml code. I think I was calculating my totals before the job got a chance to finish loading so, when I moved my calculation to after the job finished loading, it worked.  Here's the code that I changed:

**BEFORE**

```
    partial class SafetyIssue
    {

        partial void OnLoaded()
        {
            JobNumber.CalculateSafetyIssueTotals();  // I needed to move this to the JobNumber partial class
        }

    }

    partial class SafetyIssueTotals
    {
       public void RefreshTotals(List<SafetyIssue> safetyIssues)
       {
           TotalSubmissions = safetyIssues.Count(c => c.SafetyCategory == 1);
           TotalInductions = safetyIssues.Count(c => c.SafetyCategory == 2);
           TotalSafetyMeetings = safetyIssues.Count(c => c.SafetyCategory == 3); 
           TotalToolboxTalk = safetyIssues.Count(c => c.SafetyCategory == 4);
           TotalRecognitions = safetyIssues.Count(c => c.SafetyCategory == 5);
           TotalIncidents = safetyIssues.Count(c => c.SafetyCategory == 6);
           ActualSafetySubmissions = safetyIssues.Count(c => c.JobSafetyNo.Trim() != "");
       }

    }


    partial class JobNumber:IDataErrorInfo
    {

        public void CalculateSafetyIssueTotals()
        {
            if (SafetyIssuesTotals == null)
                SafetyIssuesTotals = new SafetyIssuesTotals();


            SafetyIssuesTotals.TotalActualSafetySubmissions = SafetyIssues.Count;
            SafetyIssuesTotals.TotalIncidents =
                SafetyIssues.Count(s => s.SafetyCategory1 != null && s.SafetyCategory1.SafetyCategoryID == 6);
            SafetyIssuesTotals.TotalInductions =
                SafetyIssues.Count(s => s.SafetyCategory1 != null && s.SafetyCategory1.SafetyCategoryID == 2);
            SafetyIssuesTotals.TotalRecognitions =
                SafetyIssues.Count(s => s.SafetyCategory1 != null && s.SafetyCategory1.SafetyCategoryID == 5);
            SafetyIssuesTotals.TotalSafetyMeetings =
                SafetyIssues.Count(s => s.SafetyCategory1 != null && s.SafetyCategory1.SafetyCategoryID == 3);
            SafetyIssuesTotals.TotalSubmissions =
                SafetyIssues.Count(s => s.SafetyCategory1 != null && s.SafetyCategory1.SafetyCategoryID == 1);
            SafetyIssuesTotals.TotalToolboxTalk =
                SafetyIssues.Count(s => s.SafetyCategory1 != null && s.SafetyCategory1.SafetyCategoryID == 4);

        }

    }
```

**After**

```
    partial class SafetyIssue
    {

    }

    partial class SafetyIssueTotals
    {
       public void RefreshTotals(List<SafetyIssue> safetyIssues)
       {
           TotalSubmissions = safetyIssues.Count(c => c.SafetyCategory == 1);
           TotalInductions = safetyIssues.Count(c => c.SafetyCategory == 2);
           TotalSafetyMeetings = safetyIssues.Count(c => c.SafetyCategory == 3); 
           TotalToolboxTalk = safetyIssues.Count(c => c.SafetyCategory == 4);
           TotalRecognitions = safetyIssues.Count(c => c.SafetyCategory == 5);
           TotalIncidents = safetyIssues.Count(c => c.SafetyCategory == 6);
           ActualSafetySubmissions = safetyIssues.Count(c => c.JobSafetyNo.Trim() != "");
       }

    }


    partial class JobNumber:IDataErrorInfo
    {

        partial void OnLoaded()
        {
           CalculateSafetyIssueTotals(); //moved the call to the function here. 
        }

        public void CalculateSafetyIssueTotals()
        {
            if (SafetyIssuesTotals == null)
                SafetyIssuesTotals = new SafetyIssuesTotals();


            SafetyIssuesTotals.TotalActualSafetySubmissions = SafetyIssues.Count;
            SafetyIssuesTotals.TotalIncidents =
                SafetyIssues.Count(s => s.SafetyCategory1 != null && s.SafetyCategory1.SafetyCategoryID == 6);
            SafetyIssuesTotals.TotalInductions =
                SafetyIssues.Count(s => s.SafetyCategory1 != null && s.SafetyCategory1.SafetyCategoryID == 2);
            SafetyIssuesTotals.TotalRecognitions =
                SafetyIssues.Count(s => s.SafetyCategory1 != null && s.SafetyCategory1.SafetyCategoryID == 5);
            SafetyIssuesTotals.TotalSafetyMeetings =
                SafetyIssues.Count(s => s.SafetyCategory1 != null && s.SafetyCategory1.SafetyCategoryID == 3);
            SafetyIssuesTotals.TotalSubmissions =
                SafetyIssues.Count(s => s.SafetyCategory1 != null && s.SafetyCategory1.SafetyCategoryID == 1);
            SafetyIssuesTotals.TotalToolboxTalk =
                SafetyIssues.Count(s => s.SafetyCategory1 != null && s.SafetyCategory1.SafetyCategoryID == 4);

        }


    }
```